# Open-source rule-based pattern matching / information extraction frameworks?

Tags: text, open-source, nlp, named, information-extraction

I'm shopping for an open-source framework for writing natural language grammar rules for pattern matching over annotations. You could think of it like regexps but matching at the token rather than character level. Such a framework should enable the match criteria to reference other attributes attached to the input tokens or spans, as well as modify such attributes in an action.

There are three options I know of which fit this description:

- [GATE Java Expressions over Annotations (JAPE)](http://gate.ac.uk/sale/tao/splitch8.html#chap%3ajape)
- [Stanford CoreNLP's TokensRegex](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tokensregex.shtml#Mail)
- [UIMA](http://uima.apache.org/) [Ruta](http://uima.apache.org/ruta.html) ([Tutorial](http://uima.apache.org/gscl13.html#gscl.tutorial))
- [Graph Expression (GExp)](http://code.google.com/p/graph-expression/)*

**Are there any other options like these available at this time?**

*Related Tools*

- While I know that general parser generators like [Antlr](http://www.antlr.org/) can also serve this purpose, I'm looking for something which are more specifically tailored for natural language processing or information extraction.
- [UIMA](http://uima.apache.org/) includes a [Regex Annotator](http://uima.apache.org/d/uima-addons-current/RegularExpressionAnnotator/RegexAnnotatorUserGuide.html) plugin for declaring rules in XML, but appears to operate at the character rather than high-level objects.
- I know that this kind of task is often performed with statistical models, but for narrow, structured domains there's benefit in hand-crafting rules.

* With GExp 'rules' are actually implemented in code but since there are so few options I chose to include it.

Comment: [TextMarker](http://sourceforge.net/projects/textmarker/) seems to be the JAPE equivalent for UIMA. But I haven't used it myself.

Comment: Thank you, that's a good addition to the list.

Comment: Ruta (formerly TextMarker) has a nice tutorial, give it a try

Comment: [Gate](https://gate.ac.uk/)  General Arch for Text Engineering - a full-lifecycle open source solution for text processing

Answer (score 0):

You may also check HTQL.  It supports regular expression search of tokens.  An example to search for state and zip from US address is:

```
a=htql.RegEx(); 
a.setNameSet('states', states);
a.reSearchList(address.split(), r"&[ws:states]<,>?<\d{5}>", case=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

French academic soft Unitex from University Paris East also matches your description (http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~unitex/)

It's C++ based, comprises many optional preprocessing rules and lexicons for 20+ languages.

The GUI is graph based (you design automata ie 'grammars').